# Inherit from a custom control using fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

The project I am working on is using the JavaFx framework, and therefore we are using fxml files and Scene Builder. I have made a custom control for our application following examples I have found on the [web](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm), and it works beautifully.  However, we are going to have multiple custom controls with common base functionality.  I would like to therefore, inherit the base functionality into a custom control.

What I am trying to do is to create a custom control that extends a custom root control class. This is what the CustomControl.fxml file looks like:

```
<?import com.custom.CustomRootControl ?>

<fx:root type="CustomRootControl" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    /* Add children here... */
</fx:root>
```

Right now my CustomRootControl class looks like this:

```
public class CustomRootClass extends Pane {
    /* Customization to be performed */
}
```

It is skin and bones, and I don't expect to see much in Scene Builder when I open CustomControl.fxml, but the fxml file won't open in Scene Builder.  Instead, I get the following error message:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: <path_to_CustomControl.fxml>

    ...

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: <path_to_CustomControl.fxml>

    ...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.custom.CustomRootControl
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    ...
```

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do?  And if so, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Why on Earth would someone downvote this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must insert this in your fxml file

```
 <?scenebuilder-classpath-element <path_to_CustomControl.jar>?>
```

Comment: I can't get this to work.  I am using Maven with its default project structure. My fxml file is in project/src/main/resources/fxml directory and my jar is in project/target directory.  I added <?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../../../target?> to my fxml file, but still get the "CustomRootControl not a valid type" LoadException error when I try to open with SceneBuilder.

Comment: target.jar is the jar file that contains CustomRootControl ? Does It Exist?

Comment: My jar path is ../../../../target/MyCustomProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in relation to CustomControl.fxml.  In addition to what I posted in the comments, I have tried <?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../../../target/MyCustomProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?>.  I found an alternative solution by importing MyCustomProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar into scenebuilder's library folder, but I don't know which solution is the best.

Comment: With  <?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../../../target/MyCustomProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?> does SceneBuilder open your fxml file ?

Comment: No, I get a LoadException: CustomRootControl not a valid type.